# Django-stubs doesn't ignore import

Tags: python, django, mypy, pre-commit.com, django-stubs

I've tried to configurate pre-commit + mypy + django-stubs, so I have error when i try to commit.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ'

**My configs:**

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: ''
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        exclude: "[a-zA-Z]*/(migrations)/(.)*"
        args: [--config=setup.cfg,
               --no-strict-optional,
               --ignore-missing-imports]
        additional_dependencies: [django-stubs]
```

setup.cfg

```
[mypy]
allow_redefinition = True
check_untyped_defs = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
incremental = True
strict_optional = True
show_traceback = True
warn_no_return = False
warn_unused_ignores = True
warn_redundant_casts = True
warn_unused_configs = True
plugins = mypy_django_plugin.main
show_column_numbers = True

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = config.settings.local

[mypy_django_plugin]
ignore_missing_model_attributes = True

[mypy-*.migrations.*]
# Django migrations should not produce any errors:
ignore_errors = True
```

It's look like mypy ignore option ignore_missing_imports = True.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Full error trace:

```
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to /home/**/.cache/pre-commit/patch1646008720-58913.
[WARNING] The 'rev' field of repo 'https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy' appears to be a mutable reference (moving tag / branch).  Mutable references are never updated after first install and are not supported.  See https://pre-commit.com/#using-the-latest-version-for-a-repository for more details.  Hint: `pre-commit autoupdate` often fixes this.
trim trailing whitespace.................................................Passed
fix end of files.........................................................Passed
check yaml...............................................................Passed
black....................................................................Passed
isort....................................................................Passed
dotenv-linter........................................(no files to check)Skipped
yamllint.................................................................Passed
flake8...................................................................Passed
mypy.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: mypy
- exit code: 1
Error constructing plugin instance of NewSemanalDjangoPlugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/bin/mypy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_entry())
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy/__main__.py", line 12, in console_entry
    main(None, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
  File "mypy/main.py", line 96, in main
  File "mypy/main.py", line 173, in run_build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 180, in build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 231, in _build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 478, in load_plugins
  File "mypy/build.py", line 456, in load_plugins_from_config
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/main.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.django_context = DjangoContext(django_settings_module)
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 95, in __init__
    apps, settings = initialize_django(self.django_settings_module)
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 77, in initialize_django
    settings._setup()
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/**/.cache/pre-commit/repon7zquz0p/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/**/project/config/settings/local.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import *  # noqa
  File "/home/**/project/config/settings/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    import environ
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ'
```

*I have to write some more text here, because stackoverflow get error: a lot of code, add details.*

Comment: Can you share the exact line of code that produces the error and the full error traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington I've updated my post and added full error trace. Thanks for the help

Comment: The `ignore_missing_imports` option tells mypy to ignore imports it cannot find but your interpreter still needs to be able to import it. I think whatever Python interpreter is running the mypy check doesn't have the `django-environ` package, or whatever package you use, installed

Comment: @IainShelvington, of course I have django-environ in my virtual env, and it's in dependencies on pipinev. If I start development runserver - everything is ok. When I try start it in production with docker-compose, its ok too. Does the pre-commit use my virtualenv?

Comment: I believe it uses an isolated venv, could test this by adding django-environ to additional_dependencies in `.pre-commit-config.yaml`?

Comment: looks like `django-stubs` violates the idea of a "static type checker" and imports your code

Comment: @IainShelvington after this fix I have error 

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the POSTGRES_DB environment variable. 

This variable is in my .env file. And .env file in .gitignore.

Comment: I create separate question for it, because it's different questions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303990/how-to-get-env-to-pre-commit-mypy-django-stubs