# How to get .env to pre-commit + mypy + django-stubs

Tags: python, django, mypy, pre-commit.com, django-stubs

I try to configurate start mypy + django-stubs cheking before commiting. I use pre-commit for it.
When I try to commit, I have error *django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the POSTGRES_DB environment variable*. This variable is in .env file, I export variables from .env to Django config using django-environ. And of course .env in .gitignore. So, as far as I understand: pre-commit starts with its own virtual environment, and it doesn't know about my .env file.

Above all, do I correct to understand my situation? If I'm right, how to get variables from .env file to pre-commit enviroment?

My **.pre-commit-config.yaml** (part)

```
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: ''
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        exclude: "[a-zA-Z]*/(migrations)/(.)*"
        args: [--config=setup.cfg,
               --no-strict-optional,
               --ignore-missing-imports]
       additional_dependencies: [django-stubs, django-environ]
```

my **setup.cfg**

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.9
allow_redefinition = True
check_untyped_defs = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
incremental = True
strict_optional = True
show_traceback = True
warn_no_return = False
warn_unused_ignores = True
warn_redundant_casts = True
warn_unused_configs = True
plugins = mypy_django_plugin.main
show_column_numbers = True

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = config.settings.local

[mypy_django_plugin]
ignore_missing_model_attributes = True

[mypy-*.migrations.*]
# Django migrations should not produce any errors:
ignore_errors = True
```